# How to add custom post widgets as tags into wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, metabox

I want to make same functionality as tags working into a post. I want to add some custom file to be add as downloads, where i can add images/files/pdf from a URL, and it will saved as tags, we can delete the files names as tags do. I want to enter Filename in a text field, and url of file in another text field and add this information into selected fields. as per attached file.

[image: .]

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check ACF https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
2. Create new text field for title https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/text/
3. Create new file or text field for file https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/

You can also check link field https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/

[Adding fields to Posts](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-posts/)
When you add new field group you can set position to 'Side'.